# Многоуровневое сворачивающиеся меню (аккордеон)

Tags: jquery, menu

Не могу сделать многоуровневое сворачивающиеся меню (аккордеон) на jQuery методом `slidetoggle()`

Попробовал такой метод но при открытии "Подкатегории" закрывается "Категория 1"

```js
 

  $('.menu .menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
       $(this).find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">Продукция</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">Категория 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="">Подкатегория</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="">Подподкатегория</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">Категория 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="">Подкатегория 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.menu .menu-item-has-children').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});

$('.menu-item').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="">Продукция</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">Категория 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="">Подкатегория</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="">Подподкатегория</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="">Категория 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="">Подкатегория 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Привет, сработало, но когда открываю первый раз "Категория 1" -  сразу открывается "Подкатегория" и "Подподкатегория"

Comment: Всё сработало спасибо!